# retracting and asserting values in prolog

Tags: prolog, assert

I have been modelling some directive graphs in prolog. It consists of nodes and edges and how they are connected. Every node has a certain value of surfers (page rank).
e.g.

```
e(a,c).
e(b,a).
e(b,h).

:-dynamic s/2.
s(a,1).
s(b,1).
s(c,1).
```

I have written an interpreter. This interpreter calculates new values for each node.
The problem is how to assign these new values to the database.
I have been doing it with retractall(s(*,*)) and asserting new values to every single node with e.g. assertz(s(a,sum0), 
assertz(s(b,sum1), ....
This has been working, but is it possible to assert new values without asserting each particular node in the graph a value, so that the interpreter is completely independent from the graph?
I have been trying to generate a list with all nodes in a graph and indicating the nodes of a graph in this list.

```
sum_nodes_0(X,Y):-
list_nodes(_,L),
amount_nodes(N),
nth1(I,L,X),I=<N,sum_node(X,Y).

reset(X,S):-
list_nodes(_,L),
s(X,S),
sum_node(X,Y),
retractall(s(_,_)),
forall(member(X,L),assertz(s(X,Y))).
```

sum_nodes_0 displays me the new values like.

```
X = a,
Y = 1.0 ;
X = b,
Y = 1 ;
X = c,
Y = 2 ;
X = d,
Y = 0.5 ;
X = e,
Y = 1.5 ;
X = f,
Y = 0.5 ;
X = g,
Y = 1 ;
X = h,
Y = 0.5.
```

These  values I want to be assigned by reset(X,S). But reset just resets one value not all. e.g.
    X=h; Y=0

I have tried foreach, forall and member  predicates. But it didn't work as intended.
I hope that someone has an idea.